# What does 'I feel sorry for my job' mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I wonder what the following sentence means:

I feel sorry for my job.

Does it mean that I feel dissatisfied or unhappy with my work? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a standard expression, so we would need more context.

Comment: I just want a way to say 'I am dissatisfied with my work'. Can I use the word 'sorry' in it?

Comment: "I'm not happy with/at my job".

Comment: Would it be better to say 'I feel sorry for myself working in my job"?

Comment: People would understand that, but usually we "feel sorry for" others, as in sympathy.

Comment: ic... Can I say 'I feel sorry about my job" to mean "I am unhappy with my job"?

Comment: If I heard someone say "sorry _about_ my work", I would think they were apologizing for doing a bad job. You might want to post basic questions like this on [English Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @chet You could say, "I feel sorry for _(pity)_ myself because of my job".

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the cited example isn't something a native speaker would say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sorry for someone is to pity them and to express sympathy for them. 'My brother just lost his job - I feel sorry for him.'

You feel sorry for yourself when you pity yourself and when you are miserable on account of your own suffering. 'My brother just got 'flu - he is feeling very sorry for himself.'

'I feel sorry for my work' does not seem to have an immediate meaning without more explanation. You pity your work and you sympathise with its suffering. That does not seem to mean anything. Work has no feelings. It does not get miserable.

"I am deeply unhappy at work. I am feeling very sorry for myself." That may be the nearest you can get to using the word 'sorry' to express dissatisfaction with work.

---

Another meaning of 'to feel sorry for' is to regret. "I feel sorry for the way I spoke to you just now." That is, I regret the way I spoke. With this meaning, to feel sorry *for* something is the same as to feel sorry *about* it. (Actually to apologise would be to say: "I *am* sorry for the way I spoke to you.")

"I don't feel sorry for that candidate's defeat. He deserved to lose." In this example both meanings are elided. I do not feel sorry for (sympathise with) the candidate. Also, I do not regret his defeat.

Comment: Hello, Stephen. Please look at the Help Center, and at other threads, to build up a picture of what type and what standard of question is suitable on ELU, and when not to answer questions. "Feel sorry for" is easily found by googling, and is uniformly stated to require a sentient object.